# SQL stored procedure try/catch odd behavior when called from Python

Tags: python, sql

I have a stored procedure on my sql server being called from a python script. The SP contains a TRY/CATCH block. The SP retrieves data from multiple databases, and on one table, a specific select permission needs to be granted. The table is used in an inner join for an update statement of a temp table within the SP. When the TRY/CATCH block is active, the permission exception is caught, however, when I remove the TRY/CATCH block, and execute from Python, the exception is not caught and the SP executes Correctly and I get a result set!!

If I remove the inner join to the specific table needing the permission, everything works fine even with the TRY/CATCH block.

Any ideas on where to even start researching?

Comment: share some of your code and query.

Comment: In my humble opinion, I feel that the description above is sufficient for a theoretical question. There is way too much code even if I wanted to share some. But the fact that everything works as expected other than the two cases I described tells me that the problem might not be in the code itself, but rather something very particular that only someone who might have encountered the same problem would know.

Comment: if any error comes exception will be raised , it does not matter that it is inside of try/except or not. with try/except you are able to catch exception. if you are removing try/except, there must be same exception(if running in same environment) but you are unable to see it because it will be handled in outer block. if you don't share exact exception and code, it is very hard to tell solution.

Comment: But that is exactly the opposite of what I am trying to describe. If I remove the BEGIN TRY/END TRY/ BEGIN CATCH/END CATCH blocks, no exception is caught, and the code returns the correct result set, no errors of any kind, everything works as expected

Comment: that is why we need your code and exception. just share line where exception is raised and try/catch